# Bash script to delete certain files from "semi-sequentially" numbered directories?

Tags: bash, rm

I have directories that are sequentially numbered 1001, 1002, 1003, etc... Some directories may not exist so we may see instances like 1001, 1002, 1003, 1007, 1008, etc... and I want to delete all files within those directories that are over 2 years (730 days) old.  Can someone point me in the right direction to write a bash script to automate the process?

I have what I think are 2 parts to the puzzle but I am not able to make them work together...

1. find numbered directories:
   for i in $(seq 1000 1999)
2. files older than 2 years:
   find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +730 -exec rm -rf {} ;

Comment: So is the only problem you have telling `find` to filter for numbers? (That is: Please focus on the specific technical step you need help with).

Comment: ...also, do you want to delete _the directories as a whole_ only, or sometimes to delete content _in_ a directory but not the directory itself (if the content has an older mtime than the directory that contains it)?

Comment: ...note that you _don't_ need a `for` loop. Much more efficient to let just one copy of `find` do the filtering for numbered directories itself, instead of starting `find` over and over and over with a different number given to it each time.

Comment: i do not want to delete the entire directory.  i just need to go to directory 1000 and only delete files within that are older than 2 years, then jump to directory 1001 and delete all files older than 2 years, then 1002, and so on... until i get to directory 1999.

Comment: You want to delete files, not directories, so do not find directories `-type d`, find files `-type f`. `i just need to go t` `find` already "goes to", just `find .` and it will "go to" every directory.

Comment: It sounds like you want something more like `find . -regex '.*/1[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/.*' -type f -ctime +730` (haven't tested that, might need to adjust the regextype in use)

Comment: `find . -regex '^./[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/.*' -type f -ctime +730|xargs rm -f`

Comment: @ufopilot, `| xargs rm -f` is buggy. Try filenames with quotes or spaces for example, and filenames with newlines are even worse.

Comment: @ufopilot, ...either use `find ... -exec rm -f -- {} +` (a POSIX-standardized usage which gives you all the same efficiency improvements xargs does), or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f --` (which is an extension, but one supported in both BSD and GNU worlds).